# How to find the largest count of <td>'s in a tree having multiple tables-JS

Tags: javascript

I have multiple tables in a dOM tree and I want to calculate the count of cells in every table.

code:

```
function tree() {
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    for (var p = 0, tr; tr= table[p]; p++) {
      for (var i =0, row; row = tr.rows[i]; i++) {
         console.log(row.cells.length)
      }
    }
}
```

console.log(tree())

html:

```
<table>
   <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>second</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

In the first  there are 4 cells and second  there are 2 cells I want to print out the cells with largest count in a table. Hence the o/p will be:

```
4
```

my above js code, returns the total length of all the cells in a table. How can I traverse through the tables in a tree and find the largest count of cells?

thx!

Comment: Are any tables nested within another table? Do you want the count - in this case `4` - or a reference to the `<table>` that contains the largest number of `<td>` elements?

Comment: I just want the count of tds in every tbale and no there wont be nested tables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to simplify this.

The below code will output `4` as in your OP. It's a simple modification to get the *table* with the most cells, which I suspect is what you meant (it's unclear).

```js
// Get your list of all tables in the document.
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');

// Map list of tables to list of number of <td> elements.
const lengths = 
  Array.from(tables)
    .map(table => table.querySelectorAll('td').length)

// Get the max of the list of lengths and log to console.
const max = Math.max(...lengths);
console.log(max);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>row</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>and</td>
     <td>second</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to if you want :

```
const maxTdTable = ()=>{
  var object;
  var maxCol = 0;
  $('table').each(function(element){
    $(element).each(function(elem){
      max = $(elem).childNodes.length;
      maxCol = max>=maxCol ? max : maxCol ; 
    });
  });
  return {element : object,max : maxCol};
}
```

Comment: thanks @Conan for the answer, this will def help for future ref when using Jquery.=, currently for my task I'm using pure js